New questions on answers space
I have with some frequency observed repeated or related questions on answers space. To illustrate this idea, supose this example situation:
Question:
How to solve the problem var==NULL?
Answer 1:
Set the variable with some value.
Answer 2:
I having the same problem here, even that I set the variable with value.
The problem is that Answer 2 is a new question, may be related or be the same as original question, but is arguable that it should not be in the answer space.
This is a topic where this happens for real.
Although the new question is legit, StackExchange do not have the forum structure and organization, I believe that it should not have new questions in answer space.
I can imagine two possible actions:

Downvote the answer with the new question.
Delete/Suggest to ask new questions on the comments space.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

You can flag the answer, perhaps leave a comment saying to create a new question instead.
Moderation will delete answers flagged as not an answer. Unfortunately we don't have the option to create a question from it.

Yes I can see, there is this option "Not an answer" in Flag report, thanks.
